# iterate through contents of file using shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement where I have to iterate through files and run command against data present, how do I achieve this using shell:

For ex : Files are listed as below,

```
DB_XX_X
DB_XX
DB_XXX_XX_XX
DB_XX
```

Each file content is another string list like below:(Any random string)

```
TBXX
TBXXX
TBXX_XX
TBX_XX_ABC
```

I want to iterate through files and their content and run a curl command. So that I'm able to do curl against content of each file

```
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX/TBXX/
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX/TBXX_XX/
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX/TBXXX/
```

and then next file

```
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX_X/TBX_XX_ABC/
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX_X/TBXXXXX/
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX_X/TBX/
curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar 'http://hostname/DB_XX_X/TB/
```

and so on.

Comment: The general question is answered by [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). How this *differs* from that general question is not all that clear on a read.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it simple and sticking with bash built-in functionality, this would look like:

```
for file in *; do
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar "http://hostname/$file/$line" </dev/null
  done <"$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can build the URLs from those files:

```
awk '{print "http://hostname/"FILENAME"/"$0}' DB*
```

Example:

```
~$ cat DB_1
TB_A
TB_B
TB_C
TB_D
~$ cat DB_2
TB_A
TB_B
TB_C
~$ awk '{print "http://hostname/"FILENAME"/"$0}' DB*
http://hostname/DB_1/TB_A
http://hostname/DB_1/TB_B
http://hostname/DB_1/TB_C
http://hostname/DB_1/TB_D
http://hostname/DB_2/TB_A
http://hostname/DB_2/TB_B
http://hostname/DB_2/TB_C
```

You can then use `xargs` to capture that stdout and pass it into the `curl` command:

```
awk '{print "http://hostname/"FILENAME"/"$0}' DB* | xargs -I % curl -sN --negotiate -u foo:bar %
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but file names are not consistent, it can be DB_1 or xyz_asd_adsd or just abcd. Also there are atleast 700 files and each has atleast 50 lines again without any particular naming pattern.

Comment: That's fine. If it's just the entire directory that has to be treated like this, then just do `/your/folder/*` at the end. It'll be happy with whatever you send it. If you want to do particular files, then you can specify them at the end instead like `awk -F"_" '<bigawkscript>' file1 file2 file3 file4 /some/other/file5 file6`

Comment: thank you, just one more thing and apologies its because question isn't very clear.
required string from my question : 

    http://hostname/DB_2/TB_A,B,C,D,E etc/

By above I meant :

    http://hostname/DB_2/TB_A

    http://hostname/DB_2/TB_B

    http://hostname/DB_2/TB_C

and so on .

Comment: I have edited the question now for clarity, thanks in advance

Comment: Oh! ok. That's quite a bit easier then

Comment: Why introduce the extra bugs involved in `xargs`? If you have a line with whitespace, f/e, it'll be split into multiple requests, rather than letting curl translate it to `%20`.